# Error with using json openweathermap ['daily'] (python, flet)

Tags: python, flutter, openweathermap, flet

New update, i tink, openweathermap, so i cant use ['daily'] in my json datas and i cant find the documentation that will give ,me answer

here is example:

```
src=f"./assets/icon/{_current.json()['daily'][index]['weather'][0]['icon']}@2x.png"

src=f"./assets/icon/{_current.json()['daily'][index]['weather'][0]['icon']}@2x.png"
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^
KeyError: 'daily'
```

I want to get my icons with use json but ['daily'] and another conditions like this doest work. I cant find any examples on openweathermap.org

Comment: why not just ask them to hand out the new JSON schema?

Comment: Have you inspected the content of `_current.json()` to see what keys *are* available?

Comment: Thanks for the help, I'm just a beginner and some trivial things cause me problems